# How do I check my Backup address for my Gmail account?

Tags: gmail

Can anyone tell me how to find out my secondary email address I used for my Gmail account?

Answer (score 3):

Just go here: https://myaccount.google.com/email
You will see your primary and recovery email settings there.

Answer (score 1):

That information is with your Google Account profile. There are several paths to get there. One way is to click your profile photo while you're in Gmail to open the account change menu, then click on "Account".

Or you can go directly to the URL https://www.google.com/settings. The recovery e-mail address is on the "Personal Info" tab and editable on the "Security" tab.